# Unable to use GeoJSON using leaflet package in R

Tags: r, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to plot the GeoJSON in R using Leaflet package. Below is the code and the error.

```
library(geojsonio)
library(leaflet)
library(data.table)
library(plyr)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(rgeos) #for simplification
library(leafletR)
library(sf)
library(jsonlite)
library(RJSONIO)

mydata <- fromJSON("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/senthilthyagarajan/eb7a2771eab4639e94d5f9eaad28cb33/raw/1cfe355a56d2c1856a70a5389a4eadf06d782748/data.geojson",flatten=TRUE)


leaflet(mydata) %>%
  addPolygons(color = "#444444", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,
              opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.5,
              fillColor = ~colorQuantile("YlOrRd", nghbrhd)(nghbrhd),
              highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "white", weight = 2,
                                                  bringToFront = TRUE))


Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       FeatureCollection
                     (right here) ------^
```

Please ignore the long list of packages mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to feed `leaflet` the path to a geoJSON file, not an R object read in from a geoJSON file.

Use `download.file` to get the file from the server, then run `leaflet(filepath)`.

You might want to try mapview https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mapview/index.html for mapping spatial objects with leaflet instead.